# When Order of CSS Matters?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hope you can help me :)

for example if I have this in css file:

```
#quick-links a.responsive-menu-link:before, #quick-links a.responsive-menu-linker:before, .responsive-tab > a.responsive-tab-link { 
    font-size: 1.455em;
}
```

How do I know which goes first, second, and so on...

Do I need to put for example `.responsive-tab` first in order or `#quick-links` can stay first ?

Is this kind of order is not important ?

or in what way I should do it when more then one has the same style settings.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add your code into snippet and must read-> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should read up on [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), though that is meaningless in your situation as you have a comma separated list of selectors to apply a style to. The order in which styles are declared is only important when you have styles of the same specificity, then, the last declared style gets preference.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, order is not important. If an element matches any of them, the style will be used, unless a more specific style overrides it.

Comment: You may want to expand this and explain.  Otherwise, it just looks like a comment as you are not addressing the core question.